# If $a_n \in \mathbb{Z}$ from $\left \{ a_n \right \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, then $a_n$ is constant $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Supose that the sequence $\left \{ a_n \right \}$ converge, where
> $a_{n}$ are integers. What can you say about $\left \{ a_n \right \}$?

Intuitively I got that each $a_n=c$ where $c \in \mathbb{Z}$ is a constant $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. But, I'm not how to prove it or if my idea is wrong. I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Your answer is close, but not quite correct. Consider the sequence $5,9,3,8,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,\ldots$. The sequence converges to $1$, but isn't constant.

Answer (score 2):

Let $L$ be the limit. Then for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$.

From this definition, there are several immediate claims.

**Claim 1:** The number $L$ is an integer.

Proof. Suppose $L$ is not an integer. Then there exists an integer $k$ such that $L\in (k,k+1)$. Choose $\epsilon>0$ such that $(L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon)\subset (k,k+1)$.  Then $a_n \not\in (L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon)$ for all $n$, a contradiction. Hence, $L$ is an integer.

**Claim 2:** There exists $n_0$ such that $a_n=L$ for all $n\geq n_0$.

See if you can prove this.